# mysql: how to sum 2 fields in the table and put the result in the 3rd field?

Tags: php, mysql

lets say our table has the following structure

```
        col1 | col2 | col3
```

I want to sum col1 and col2 then update the col3 with the result

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE tablename SET col3 = col1 + col2
```